# TFS Build vNext rest api: queue build requested for

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to queue a new build from **PowerShell** using the **TFS Rest API**. I'm able to queue a new build but I would like to set the requestedBy property. In the [docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build) one can read that you can pass additional parameters. I can't find any further documentation on what these parameters can be. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Using the `tfsbuild.exe` (to queue XAML builds) you can pass an additional argument like this:

```
&$tfsBuild.Exe start "url" project definition /requestedFor:"$buildRequestedFor" /queue
```

**edit**

I've been able to get this working. The body of the request looks like:

```
$json = "{
        ""definition"": {
            ""id"" : 174
        }
        ,""requestedFor"": {
            ""id"": ""6f4d7323-fa51-4cda-9eb4-7342b02ba087""
        }
      }" `
```

You can only use the id propery. Using uniqueName for example will fail.

Here's the full **PowerShell** code:

```
$user = ""
$pass= ""

$uri = "http://Instance/DefaultCollection/Project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"

$json = "{
        ""definition"": {
            ""id"" : 174
        }
        ,""requestedFor"": {
            ""id"": ""6f4d7323-fa51-4cda-9eb4-7342b02ba087""
        }
      }" 

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $secpasswd)

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Credential $cred -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json
```

Comment: Related (for vNext): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326058/tfsbuild-command-line-vnext-2015

Comment: Seems to be a powershell solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496022/start-vnext-build-from-powershell-and-get-artifacts

Comment: I don't see why those two links help. I can trigger a new build, that's not the problem. I can't set the requestedBy property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to get this working. The body of the request looks like:

```
$json = "{
        ""definition"": {
            ""id"" : 174
        }
        ,""requestedFor"": {
            ""id"": ""6f4d7323-fa51-4cda-9eb4-7342b02ba087""
        }
      }"
```

You can only use the id propery. Using uniqueName for example will fail.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use PowerShell to queue a build with the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376206/how-to-trigger-a-build-in-tfs-2015-using-rest-api) might help. The challenge is that the REST API doesn't look like it's fully documented yet so  there are some properties that can only be found by using a tool like Fiddler. You might be able to change the body to be something like this but I haven't tried it yet.

```
$body = @"
        { 
            "definition": {
                "id": $Build_Definition_ID
            },
            "sourceVersion": {
                "requestedBy": {name here}
            }
        }
    "@
```

Here's an example that you should be able to modify (missing declaration of a few variables but this should get you started):

```
$body = @"
    { 
        "definition": {
            "id": $Build_Definition_ID
        } 
    }
"@

$baseUri = $TFSInstanceURL+"/"+$ProjectCollection+"/"+$TeamProject+"/_apis/build"

$postUri = $baseUri+"/builds?api-version=2.0"

Write-Host $postUri

##Create a new PSCredential based on username/password

$securePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $securePassword)

### Queue a build ###

##Call the REST API for TFS that does a POST request to queue a build with the body of the request to be the build definition

$buildResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Credential $credential -ContentType application/json -Uri $postUri -Body $body

Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json $buildResponse)
```

See this [link](http://blog.nwcadence.com/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases/) for more examples.